# 100% height div inside table-cell not working on Firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a two column 100% height layout using the display table-cell property. It is working fine on Chrome, but I'm not having success on Firefox nor IE.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ehfa0kk8/5/

Take a look at how it works on Chrome. Any idea of how to make this work?

```
<div id="table">
    <div id="row">
        <div id="cell_1">
            <div id="overflown_div">
                long content goes here...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="cell_2">
            Blah blah blah
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#table {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}

#row {
    display: table-row;
}

#cell_1, #cell_2 {  
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
}

#cell_1 {
    width: 390px;
    background: aliceblue;
}

#cell_2 {
    background: yellow;
}

#overflown_div {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

UPDATE: First, there should be enough content on the left column so it will overflow. On Chrome it shows a scroll bar so you can scroll just the content of that column (cell). On Firefox it doesn't happen.

EXAMPLE:
[image]

Comment: What isn't working? I see 2 full height columns in Firefox.

Comment: First, I don't know how big is your screen, but there should be a long content on the left column so it will overflown. On Chrome it shows a scroll bar so you can scroll just the content of that column (cell). On Firefox it doesn't happen

Comment: looks fine here on firefox, can you post a screenshot to explain the problem.

Comment: @sdcr, I just did. Notice the scrollbar on the overflown div on Chrome, but on Firefox the 100% height doesn't work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The trick is:

- Set row's `height` to `100%`
- Set cell's `height` to `0`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#table {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}
#row {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
}
#cell_1,
#cell_2 {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 0;
}
#cell_1 {
  width: 390px;
  background: aliceblue;
}
#cell_2 {
  background: yellow;
}
#overflown_div {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#overflown_div p {
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <div id="row">
    <div id="cell_1">
      <div id="overflown_div">
        <p>Blah blah blah</p>
        <p>Blah blah blah</p>
        <p>Blah blah blah</p>
        <p>Blah blah blah</p>
        <p>Blah blah blah</p>
        <p>Blah blah blah</p>
        <p>Blah blah blah</p>
        <p>Blah blah blah</p>
        <p>Blah blah blah</p>
        <p>Blah blah blah</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cell_2">
      Blah blah blah
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works for Firefox, but not for IE. Any logic behind that?

Comment: It works if you set both to 100% and if you only target Firefox. Chrome, on the other hand, needs the cell to have a **fixed** height, even zero. Full solution is: `th, td { height: 0; } @-moz-document url-prefix() { tr, th, td { height: 100%; } }` (use them in that order)