# html button size height percentage

Tags: html, button, height, percentage

How can I set the button size in HTML to be percentage of screen. Pixel units work but percentage does not.
See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3po5o7cb/10/

```
<button style="width:20%; height:20%"></button>
<button style="width:200px;height:200px"></button>
```

Answer (score 4):

> To set a percentage height, its parent element(*) must have an explicit height.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the height of the parent of that button 100% as well. See [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866074/getting-a-table-to-fill-100-height-in-a-td/45160113#45160113)